# Add a row in a DataGridView bounded to a database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bounded to a SLQ Server CE database table.

I created an Add button, when the button is pressed I would like to add a new row to the DataGridView in order to allow the user to insert new data into the DataGridView.

I also would like that the data will be persisted into the bounded database once the user finishes his input in this new row.

I have tried:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

Inside the button click event in order to insert a new row, but I get the following error message:

***Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the row to the `DataTable` or whatever object you're using to interface between the SQL and the DataGridView (in other words the object that you set `dataGridView1.DataSource` equal to).

For Example:

```
// set DataSource
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;

// add row
dataTable1.Rows.Add();
```

If you don't want to control the adding yourself, you can do what @InBetween said and set `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows` to true.

Comment: DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows is already set to true. I use Table Adapter as the interface between the DataGridView and the database, but the method myTableAdapter.Rows.Add(); doesn't exist, and if I use that method with the DataViewGrid it gives me the error that I posted before.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to interface between the two?

Comment: Hopefully you mean this:

`this.animalsTableAdapter.Fill(this.animalsDataSet.Animals);`

Which fills the DataGridView with data from the database table.

Comment: `this.animalsDataSet.Animals` is a DataTable, so `this.animalsDataSet.Animals.Rows.Add()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can allow the user to add rows by setting `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` to `true`. This will allow the user to add as many new rows as he wants and edit the values of the fields.

Another option is to add a new "default" row directly to the `DataGridView.DataSource` (`IList` or `IListSource` object). It amounts to the same thing as letting the user add rows but it has the advantage that you can control the amount of rows added (for example the user should only be allowed to add 1 row, in which case you would set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false`).

Comment: AllowUserToAddRows is already set to true, and indeed the user can add new rows (when the last row is being written, a new empty row appears at the end). But I want to allow the user to add a new row when clicking the "Add" button.

About adding a new default row directly to DataGridView.DataSource, it doesn't have an "add" method neither something similar, how would you do that?

Comment: @rfc1484: What is your datasource?